# Добавить поле в регистрацию FOSUserBundle Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony2, fosuserbundle

Всем привет. Возникла проблема с добавлением поля в форме регистрации "бандла" `FOSUserBundle`.

Вот сам код:

```
    \\src\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType.php
    <?php 
    namespace UserBundle\Form\Type;

    use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
    use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType as BaseType;

    class RegistrationFormType extends BaseType
    {
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
            $builder->add('realname');
        }

        public function getParent()
        {
            return 'fos_user_registration';
        }

        public function getName()
        {
            return 'app_user_registration';
        }
    }
```

config:

```
\\src\UserBundle\Resources\config.yml
services:
     app_user.registration.form.type:
        class: UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType
        arguments: [%fos_user.model.user.class%]
        tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: app_user_registration }
```

Entity:

```
\\src\UserBundle\Entity\User.php
namespace UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="web_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter your name.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
     * @Assert\Length(
     *     min=3,
     *     max=255,
     *     minMessage="The name is too short.",
     *     maxMessage="The name is too long.",
     *     groups={"Registration", "Profile"}
     * )
     */
    protected $realname;



    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set realname
     *
     * @param string $realname
     * @return User
     */
    public function setRealname($realname)
    {
        $this->realname = $realname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get realname
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getRealname()
    {
        return $this->realname;
    }
}
```

services:

```
\\src\UserBundle\Resources\config\services.yml
services:
     app_user.registration.form.type:
        class: UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType
        arguments: [%fos_user.model.user.class%]
        tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: app_user_registration }
```

При входе на форму регистрации ошибка: `Could not load type "app_user_registration"`.

Как исправить, можете подсказать ?

Comment: пересмотрите Ваш `\src\UserBundle\Resources\config.yml`

Comment: Как я понял дело в services, если их добавляю в корне проекта то все работает, по хоже нужно как то ссылку прописать(

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо исправить наследование типа формы, на представленную ниже:

```
// src/UserBundle/Form/Type/RegistrationFormType.php

namespace UserBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class RegistrationFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('realname');
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'fos_user_registration';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app_user_registration';
    }
}
```

`Entity` в вашем случае корректен.

Далее, необходимо зарегистрировать новый тип формы, это можно сделать либо в файле сервисов приложения, либо в файле бандла:

```
# app/config/services.yml or
# src/UserBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
services:
    app.form.registration:
        class: UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: app_user_registration }
```

И последний шаг, это указать FOSUserBundle, что для формы регистрации необходимо использовать другой тип:

```
# app/config/config.yml
fos_user:
    # ...
    registration:
        form:
            type: app_user_registration
```

В случае, если определение сервиса в файле `src/UserBundle/Resources/config/services.yml` система не увидит, значит ваш UserBundle не загружает данный файл. Это необходимо проверить, и в случае необходимости добавить:

```
// src/UserBundle/DependencyInjection/UserExtension.php

class UserExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration,     $configs);

        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');
    }
}
```

В вашем вопросе, под "config:" и "services:" заголовками кусков кода выполняется одно и тоже.

В [документации (en)](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_forms.html)  по шагам расписан ваш пример, только не выдумывайте и не добавляйте лишнего, в частности не нужен `parent::buildForm`.

Не нужен `arguments` в `app_user.registration.form.type`.